# C Function: Count the occurrences of a digit in an integer

Tags: c, count, numbers, integer, frequency

I'm receiving `Output: 1.` I should count the number of times a digit appear in an integer, for example, for number `1222345` and `n = 2` Should appear `3` times.

```
int countOccurrences(int n, int num)
{
    int i,k;

    i=0;
    while(num!=0)
    {

        k=num%10;
        num=num/10;
        if(k==n)
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
}

// Main
void main()
{
    int num= 1222345;
    int n = 2;
    printf("Occurance of a number: %d", countOccurrences(n,num));
}
```

Comment: You mean count the number of times a *digit* appears in an integer, right? Your function doesn't return anything. It needs a `return` statement to indicate what you are returning!

Comment: Please put some effort in formatting your code

Comment: This is how you do the formatting.

Comment: @kai11 What should code print when `num = 0` and `n = 0`?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to enable the compiler warning that tells you that there's no `return` statement in `countOccurrences()`.

Comment: @chux `0` is an integer with one digit. What's the issue?

Comment: @meaning-matters With a simple `return i;` fix, OP's `CountOccurrences(0,0)` returns 0, I'd expect 1 as  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48327419/2410359)

Answer (score 4):

You have undefined behavior in the code. The function is supposed to return an `int` and it didn't.

Solution is to add `return i` in the end of other function. This will give you correct result. In the `countOccurrences()` function

```
...
    if(k==n)
    {
        i++;
    }
  }
  return i;
}
```

I was skipping the discussion of error check and all that. As `chux` mentioned for `n<=0` case you might want to add a different way of handling it but you didn't add it. Atleast consider those case and put an error message on whatever input you need.

Some corner cases are

- `n=0,m=0`.
- Negative value of `n` or `m`.

Comment: OP's code also misses when `num <= 0` - but likely does not care.

Comment: @chux.: Well yes..point noted.

Answer (score 1):

Put a **return** on your **countOccurrences** function please

```
int countOccurrences (int n, int num) {

int i, k;
i = 0;
while (num! = 0)
{

     k = num% 10;
     num = num / 10;
     if (k == n)
     {
         i ++;
     }
}

return i; }
```

Answer (score 1):

As other have pointed out, there are important issues with your code.

Here is a recursive solution that you may find interesting:

```
int countOccurrences(int n, int num)
{
    int count = ((num % 10) == n);

    return (num < 10) ? count : count + countOccurrences(n, num / 10);
}
```

Few general remarks about your code:

- When using `printf()`, you should `#include <stdio.h>`.
- `main()` should return `int`.
- Place spaces around operators and format your code consistently. This `k = num % 10;` is more readable than `k=num%10;`. (There's more to code formatting than a matter of taste; without spaces you create areas full of characters which are more difficult to parse for our visual system.)

Comment: Simpler to terminate at `num == 0`, then it's simply `return num ? (num%10==n) + countOccurrences(n, num/10) : 0;`

Comment: @TobySpeight Very nice!  It would change the behaviour though as (0, 0) would return 0, instead of 1 as it does now. Since `0` is an integer with one digit, it would no longer be correct.

Comment: Oh yes, I did forget the edge case of (0,0).  Can I claim that's because the unit tests are missing?  (Well, it was worth a try...)